# Create contact before espresso test

Tags: android, android-espresso

In my android application I need test edit fragment with ability to choose contact   from android contacts.

My question is: Is there is the way to create contact before android espresso test and without WRITE_CONTACTS permission in manifest? Or may I mock content resolver somehow ?

Here is code how I get contact:

```
@OnClick(R.id.et_contact)
void chooseContactClick(View v) {
    launchContactPicker(v);
}

public void launchContactPicker(View view) {
    Intent contactPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,  ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(contactPickerIntent, CONTACT_PICKER_RESULT);
}

private ContactInf fetchPersonFromIntent(Intent data) {
    ContactInf contactInf = null;
    Uri uri = data.getData();
    ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
    Cursor contentCursor = cr.query(uri, null, null,null, null);
    if(contentCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        String id = contentCursor.getString(contentCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

        // Perform a query to retrieve the contact's name parts
        String[] nameProjection = new String[] {
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.MIDDLE_NAME,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME
        };
        Cursor nameCursor = cr.query(
                ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                nameProjection,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTACT_ID
                        + "=?", new String[]{id}, null);

        // Retrieve the name parts
        String firstName = StringUtils.EMPTY, middleName = StringUtils.EMPTY, lastName = StringUtils.EMPTY;
        if(nameCursor.moveToNext()) {
            firstName = nameCursor.getString(nameCursor.getColumnIndex(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.GIVEN_NAME));
            middleName = nameCursor.getString(nameCursor.getColumnIndex(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.MIDDLE_NAME));
            lastName = nameCursor.getString(nameCursor.getColumnIndex(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.FAMILY_NAME));
            String msg = String.format(" contact %s %s %s %s ", id, firstName, middleName, lastName);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            try {
                long idLong = Long.valueOf(id);
                contactInf = new ContactInf(idLong, firstName, middleName, lastName);
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, String.format(" NumberFormatException during parse id [%s] ", id));
            }
        }
    }
    return contactInf;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved my issue by adding one more manifest file into src\debug\ folder with: uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"

In this case I have WRITE_CONTACTS permission for debug and don't have it for release as expected.